# Trouble with Git, Windows, Ubuntu and Vagrant

Tags: windows, git, ubuntu, vagrant

I've recently installed a vagrant VM on my windows box running ubuntu 14.04 for development purposes. I moved an existing Git project and placed this in the (synced) /vagrant folder so that I can get to my code from windows.

When I wanted to do my first commit, I saw that all files were modified. After googling for a bit I saw that this can be solved using:

```
git config core.filemode false
```

This made most of the changed files disappear, however some are still changed. After checking these files it seems that there's somehow a different line ending.

To solve it, I first tried:

```
git checkout .
```

But this had no effect whatsoever so I started searching again and found:

```
git config core.autocrlf true|false|input
git config core.eol lf
```

I tried each of these combinations followed by a `git checkout .` and `git status` but it keeps saying that my files are modified.

Does anyone of you know a solution to this (quite annoying) issue?